# Where is the config file for IPSec Policy Filter List for Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have more than 30 IPS to be included in IP Security Filter.

Where is the config document on Windows drive located?
We want to input the data on the config file directly as using the wizard consuming more clicking and time.

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'file' on windows that does that. But you could alway iterate through your list with powershell - the command you are searching for is [Set-NetIPsecRule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/set-netipsecrule?view=win10-ps).

Entries are removed with Remove-NetIPsecRule.